# How to run WCF service on a specific port

Tags: wcf

I have a .Net 4.0 WCF service running on IIS. I have not specified a port so assume it is running on port 80. I need to install my service on a server where port 80 is already being used and the network guy had asked me to change my service to run on port 443. How do I do this? I'm guessing it can be configured in app.config but I can't find an article that shows me how.

Here is my current app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: You can map anoter port on your IIS. Just right click on your website that has the WCF Service or if the WCF service applciation is a website in your IIS then select edit bindings, now you can change the http to listen on a different port rather than 80.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming you are running your services on net.tcp protocols.

1) Edit your bindings (right click `Default Web Site` select `Edit Bindings`

[image]

2)     Server Side

```
<service name="YouServiceNameSpace.YourService">
<endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="YourBinding" contract="YourContract" />
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

3) Client Side

```
 <endpoint address="net.tcp://YourHost:443/YourServiceDirecotry/YourService.svc"
    behaviorConfiguration="YourBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="YourTcpBinding" contract="YourContract"
    name="YourContractName" />
```

Comment: Note that point 1 in the above assumes you have started IISManager and navigated to the connection corresponding to the server your web page is running on.

Answer (score 6):

We can do it using the .csproj file of the WCF project(in case of using VS).Just change the value of this xml tag in your corresponding file:

To Run the service at port number 60000 ,

```
<DevelopmentServerPort>60000</DevelopmentServerPort>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should have a services node with at least one service node and each having endpoints, where you can specify the port. See more at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx

For example:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.myServiceType">
   <endpoint 
      address="net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8000" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="myBindingConfiguration1"
      contract="MyContract"  />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.0 so it is a simplified configuration. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014.aspx This adds to the problem as I don't have a service already configured that I can change.

Comment: @SteveChadbourne You can still specify an endpoint and address, no?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the port in the address of the endpoint. See the 'Defining Endpoint Addresses in Code' section in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx) article for more details.

Comment: That's only going to work if you're self-hosting your WCF service - otherwise, the hosting environment (IIS) will dictate the service's endpoint address to a large extent...