# What Is Wrong With My ASP.NET WCF Configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service nested in an ASP.NET 4.5 web application and everything was running without issue until I attempted to specify a port.  I have to run on a separate port as per my client's requirements but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

For now I am running everything local and I did punch holes in my firewall so I know that is not the issue.  The error I get - System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:59031 - tells me that I have no listener attached so, again, it must be my config.  Right?

Here is a call:

```
http://localhost:59031/seoland/seo.svc/Login?User=test&Pass=pass
```

And here is my config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
    <services>
      <service name="seoland.extranet.seo">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="json" binding="webHttpBinding" name="MainHttpPoint" contract="seoland.extranet.seo">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MexEP" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:59031/seoland/seo.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2048000" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="json">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="false" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultBodyStyle="Bare"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding" httpGetBindingConfiguration=""/>
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
            <defaultPorts>
              <add scheme="http" port="59031"/>
            </defaultPorts>
          </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Again everything worked until I tried adding the port number - can somebody please help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you configured the port binding on the default website in IIS, or the site you are hosting your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the correct port number? Also, make sure that there is no firewall restrictions and the port is open.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quick.  I did verify that the port is correct, that it is opened in the firewall and that it is registered in IIS for the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Please check your binding settings. Try to follow this example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514766/how-to-run-wcf-service-on-a-specific-port