# Program uses port 80, but it shouldn't

Tags: c#, wcf, port

I'm creating simple application, which should communicate with hosted service. Application is pretty simple, you can find such in any WCF service tutorial, and feature one service client to connect to service. I'm using endpoint

> "http://localhost:6480/DentalDesktop/ServerAgentService"

for service, so, as I understand, application should use only 6480 port (which is open in all rules etc).
But once I'm trying to launch application, it throws exception, that port 80 is already used by another application. Some investigation showed, that this is Skype using port 80.

But, I don't get, why my application is using port 80 at all. The only client-service pair us using another port. Is this caused by some default connection of WCF application or what?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514766/how-to-run-wcf-service-on-a-specific-port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I can say... Don't use http or tcp to connect to your server from your own machine. net.pipe works perfect, without any ports.

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is the HTTP port, used by browsers for non secure traffic.

Can you give more details on the App type you are creating. is it a website, WPF application, a service, etc.

Comment: Technically it is WinForms application. It is used to communicate with service via duplex callback (WSDualHttpBinding), and initiate some tray icon related actions depending on it.

Comment: Can you post the code you have to call the service?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I made port forwarding work on a VM using iptables. You first have to enable port forwarding and then set a rule for the PREROUTING chain:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

If you want to redirect localhost traffic use this instead:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d localhost -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

These examples route traffic from port 80 to port 3000.

Comment: Problem with ports can be solved easily by configuring Skype to not use ports 80 and 443. Question was more like, why does my program use this port.

Comment: It uses the port that a programmer assigns to it. The first 1024 ports are restricted by convention, and above that you can choose the port number at which you want your service to listen. Port numbers are just numbers. For example, everybody agrees that port 80 should be the HTTP port and that is why people keep on using port 80 for HTTP.