# IIS Website Application doesnt work anything but port 80

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, networking

I wrote a WCF service in visual studio 2017. I then added this service to IIS (not the express version but the full fledge IIS). It is added as an application under the default created website. I can access my service end-point without any issues at `http://localhost/<websitename>/MyService.svc/test/123`. `/test/123` is just a simple GET endpoint.

The default website is already configured for port 80.

However, when I changed the port from 80 to say, 1234, it does not work. It merely returns me `"Service Unavailable. HTTP Error 503."` when I hit the `/test/123` endpoint.

I have already executed the console command to add the port to ACL `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:1234/ user=everyone`.

Does anyone know how can I get another port (non 80) to work?

Edit:
I am aware that there is an answer [How to run WCF service on a specific port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514766/how-to-run-wcf-service-on-a-specific-port) which explains how to bind to another port. However, the accepted answer uses the net.tcp protocol. I would like to use the HTTP protocol.

Is there any way to do it with HTTP protocol? If it cannot be done, then I guess ill have to redesign and swap over to net.tcp protocol.

I am extremely new to .NET development and WCF, so hopefully somebody with experience can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Does the answer here work?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514766/how-to-run-wcf-service-on-a-specific-port

Comment: There are many possible solutions. first, did you check your local firewall ? try turning it off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run WCF service on a specific port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514766/how-to-run-wcf-service-on-a-specific-port)

Comment: That link, that answer, talks about using net.tcp protocol. I am currently using http - so that the endpoint can be hit via a browser.

It would be highly preferential to not need to resort to using net.tcp protocol. Is there any way to remain using http protocol but map it to another port? When using IIS Express, it maps itself to some random http port (eg: 55765). Give this, it should be do-able despite hosting in IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem had nothing to do with the so-called linked answer.

Prior to running my WCF service in IIS, I was trying to deploy it as a WAS and then Console application. In my process of getting those 2 implementations to work, I had to execute the command `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:1234/ user=everyone` so that the port could be accessed.

By sheer luck, i stumbled upon this link:
https://serverfault.com/questions/666976/service-unavailable-if-i-try-to-access-iis-website-via-ip-address-works-fine-vi

Although it didnt have an accepted answer, the comments held the answer. My problem was caused exactly because I executed the `netsh` command. What happens is that the command causes that ip/port to be reserved, and thus, IIS cannot attach to the ip/port and therefore the `Service Unavailable` error. I assumed that if the WAS and Console version needed that command to be executed, then the IIS version needed it as well.

As for letting an IIS WCF Service be available on any other port, the process is super simple. Within IIS itself (Execute "inetmgr" in Run to launch), in the default or custom website you created, edit the binding and change the HTTP port to whatever port that you want. After that, its done. You should be able to access your application/website from that port via HTTP.
Eg:
`http://localhost:<some port>/<websitename>/MyService.svc/test/123`

My WCF Service config was a standard config that allowed for HTTP access.

If you would like to access it from another computer or from the internet, then you will need to configure your router to port forward your selected port (if needed) and ensure that your firewall allows data flow for that port.

Many "thanks" to the downvoters who assume this was some duplicate. Your "help" contributed in finding a solution to the problem.